# Why does Bootstrap 4 not break on mobile device?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I test this in the browser and I resize my browser to a smaller window, I see the div's stacking. But when I deploy this to my server and I go to the site on my mobile phone, it is not stacked! I've tried it on two Android devices using Chrome, both showing the same behavior.

I've also tried this, without success:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Edit:
In my index.html in the `head` section I have added the following line with no luck:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

Edit:
Case Closed: After clearing the cache on my mobile phone, it finally stacked the divs. I cannot tell whether it was because of the meta tag, but I will mark that as the accepted answer.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/ ?

Comment: @DogukanCavus Thnx. I'v tried it, but unfortunately with no luck.

Comment: So what did you try, please post entire code which relates to the question, not just the container. This is a perfectly fine example of rows that will stack below "medium" screens, so the problem lies somewhere on your end.

Comment: @DogukanCavus Could post an answer, so I can mark that as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo should add

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

in `<head>` tag. [More information](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)